Spring does not read JSON data sent from JavaScript correctly
I'm using spring boot on back-end and a jQuery on the front-end. Here's my code:
Spring Controller
@PostMapping("/updateStaff")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> updateStaff(
        @RequestBody UpdateStaffDto nhanVien
) {
    try {
        NhanVien existedNhanVien = nhanVienRepository.findById(nhanVien.getIdCode()).orElse(null);
        log.warn("Id:" + nhanVien.getIdCode());
        if (existedNhanVien != null) {
            log.warn("nhanVien found");
            String newMatKhau = (nhanVien.getMatKhau()!=null && !nhanVien.getMatKhau().isBlank())
                    ? Common.sha256Hash(nhanVien.getMatKhau()) : "";
            String newVaiTro = (nhanVien.getVaiTro()!=null && !nhanVien.getVaiTro().isBlank())
                    ? nhanVien.getVaiTro() : "";
            if(!newMatKhau.equals(existedNhanVien.getMatKhau())) {
                existedNhanVien.setMatKhau(newMatKhau);
            }
            if(!newVaiTro.equals(existedNhanVien.getVaiTro())) {
                existedNhanVien.setVaiTro(newVaiTro);
            }
            existedNhanVien.setDateUpdated(new Date());
            nhanVienRepository.save(existedNhanVien);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        log.error("Error: " + e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        log.error("System error: " + e);
    }
    log.warn("nhanVien not found");
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
}

DTO:
package com.springdemo.library.model.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class UpdateStaffDto {
    private int IdCode;
    private String matKhau;
    private String vaiTro;
}

JavaScript:
$('#update-staff-form').on('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     let matKhau = $("#password-update").val();
     let xacNhanMatKhau = $("#confirm-password-update").val();
     if(matKhau === xacNhanMatKhau) {
         modifyStaff(JSON.stringify({
                 IdCode: $('#staff-id-update').val(), //the value I passed to here is 3, it was also 3 when I logged the value of #staff-id-update out on browser console
                 matKhau: matKhau,                    //here a random string
                 vaiTro: $('#role-update').val()      //here is 0
             }),'/Library/management/updateStaff'
         );
     } else {
         $('#unmatched-password-message')
             .text("Xác nhận mật khẩu chưa khớp với mật khẩu bạn đã nhập, vui lòng nhập lại").css('color', 'red');
     }
 });

function modifyStaff(data, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            $('#time-update').text(formatDate(new Date()));
            window.location.reload();
            alert("Đã thêm tài khoản thành công");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.warn('Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert("Có lỗi");
        }
    });
}

I don't understand why my Spring controller keeps returning the IdCode as 0, and other attributes of the UpdateStaffDTO parameter were either 0 or empty. Can anyone explain why and how to fix this? Appreciate your help.
I tried to remove JSON.parse
I tried to remove the @RequestBody in my method parameter
Didn't work

I believe, without additional configuration jackson would try to use a no args constructor and setters to populate DTO. As your DTO doesn't have setters, attributes are left with default init values, that is how your "int IdCode" is 0. Throw in a @Setter on DTO for a quick check.
Actually, having @NoArgsConstructor on a class without setters doesn't make much sense - how would you populate attributes' values?
If you want your DTO to stay immutable there is an option with @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({fields..}) annotation. Either add it manually or create "lombok.config" file in the root of your project
and add line: lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true.
This will result in @java.beans.ConstructorProperties annotation being added to your class and generally should be enough for Jackson to deserialize.
More on lombok site: https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration and https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor .
